# SDWebImage Image Load Transition not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, transition, sdwebimage

I have tried following the instructions on the SDWebImage to enable an image to fade-in once loaded using their example:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    CategoryCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"categoryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.categoryCellThumbnail.sd_imageTransition = SDWebImageTransition.fadeTransition;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"url"]];
    [cell.categoryCellThumbnail sd_setImageWithURL:url];
    
    return cell;
}
```

However it doesn't seem to work. No animation ever seems to happen, and the image once loaded always appears instantly.

Comment: Via the docs - “Image transition is only applied for image from network by default. If you want it been applied for image from cache as well, using SDWebImageForceTransition option.”  . Not sure how to set that but it might be your problem.

Comment: @WarrenBurton I gave that a shot as well, but didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @AccDa hey, did you fins this solution? Seems something related to CollectionView Cell, I'm experiencing the same, for some reason don't see that fade transition, just a "jump" from a blank to downloaded image.